# How to naming a REST API which returns a list of orders which belongs to specific user?

Tags: rest

We have a REST API

```
/accounts/{user_id}/shop/orders
```

to return all of orders which belongs to a user.

Now I add new API which return orders by specific order numbers.

```
/accounts/{user_id}/shop/orders/order?orders=a,b,c,d
```

I can't name the new API to the original `/accounts/{user_id}/shop/orders` because I want to it mapping to different controller.

But I think `/accounts/{user_id}/shop/orders/order?orders=a,b,c,d` is a little bit weird, so what is better name for that case?

Comment: *I want to it mapping to different controller.* I'm curious, why?

Comment: @TimCastelijns They query different Cassandra tables...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a suggestion I have seen being used now and then, which could work in your situation considering you *must* have different endpoints for the 2 controllers.

To return all of orders which belongs to a user:

```
/accounts/{user_id}/shop/orders/all
```

or

```
/accounts/{user_id}/shop/orders/list
```

(I like the first one better, since the 2nd one does not imply that the list is complete)

To return orders by specific order numbers:

```
/accounts/{user_id}/shop/orders/filtered?number=a,b,c,d
```

---

This way you can route them both through `/accounts/{user_id}/shop/orders` which is nice since they both belong there, yet still be able to clearly distinguish between the functionality of the 2 endpoints.